# Removing Color from Sprite ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, filtering, sprite

My project loads SWF files using the Loader class, and then loads Sprite objects from those child files. Each sprite has a specific green color, and I want to substitute all pixels of one color for transparent ones.

I can re-compile these Sprites as objects of the BitmapData class, to simplify things, but I'm looking for any way that avoids operating the objects pixel-by-pixel. I'm guessing that I can use some kind of bitmap filter, but I'm just not familiar enough with ActionScript to know specifics.

Comment: I think that should be possible to do with [Pixel Bender shaders](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS3E659D01-10C0-479d-8175-B40950BBC223.html)

Comment: @fsbmain Trying to avoid embedded solutions.

Comment: what is your problem with pixel by pixel coloring? you just do this one time, no performance issue occurs

Comment: Oops. Last comment was wrong. I meant that I do it more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `threshold` with `bitmapData` of that Sprite.

### Before                           After √

[image]

---

```
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(sprite.width, sprite.height, true, 0x0);
bmd.draw(sprite);
bmd.threshold(bmd, bmd.rect, new Point(), "==", 0xff00ff00); // 0xff00ff00 = GREEN
```

you may change the green color, also you are free to setting more range of colours to be transparented, for example, some kind of detecting smooth corners like this:

[image]

just need to play with operation argument of `threshold`, i used "==", but many others available.

---

## refrences :

- [Adobe
  Doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#threshold())

Comment: So I like this, but I can still see a green background on the sprite.

Comment: @Fuselight put a preview of your sprite here please

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/5U2MZ

The actual layering works _great_. But I can still see the background.

Comment: @Fuselight background color in that sprite is same as answer, 0xff00ff00, make sure this part `sprite.bmd` must provides sprite bitmap data, please [join CHAT](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130330/actionscript)